# Problem with creating a API with php and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, api

I have a problem with creating an online api. I have created a test.php (for example) document and add some codes like the following:

```
echo json_encode("This is a test!");
```

Then I've made another php document with a few JS codes and tried to catching the data:

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onload = function(){
    $('#demo').text(this.responseText);
};
xhttp.open("GET","https://nimatahernejad.ir/tethergraph/api/last_liquidity.php");
xhttp.send();
```

when I've used it on my local it worked well. But after I uploaded my program at host I couldn't get any access to my data.
Why it's happening?

address:
https://nimatahernejad.ir/tethergraph/api/last_liquidity.php

Comment: open the developer console and check for errors

Comment: I don't have any error on my console

Comment: Is the script that runs the above AJAX script in the parent directory of `api/test.php`? Please try to clarify your server directory structure. Do you see the AJAX request being made in the network tab of the console?

Comment: https://nimatahernejad.ir/tethergraph/api/last_liquidity.php

Comment: that is my address

Comment: When one traverses the directory structure and goes to the [parent directory](https://nimatahernejad.ir/tethergraph/) I see no AJAX requests being made to `api/test.php` nor is there a file within the `api` directory called `test.php`
- The file `last_liquidity.php` returns simple JSON data so presumably that is the file that you should target in the AJAX request??

Comment: It is possibile to see the client hosted? The url of php server side is ok. The json is returned. Maybe there is something wrong with javascript? Have you tried to do same calls with postman and or with curl?

Comment: no I didn't try with curl but js works when I put my php in local. is it possible that this is happening because of security issues?

Comment: I have updated my script would you check it for me?